# CSS Content Not Downloading in Only Google Chrome

Tags: django, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

This is currently a problem with a development environment that I'm running, which is Django's built in 'development server' (the one started with `python manage.py runserver`) running on my local machine. On my deployment machine which runs FCGI this is not a problem.

*CSS files fail to download in Chrome but successfully download+render in Firefox. Both browsers get 200 OK responses from the server, but for whatever reason Chrome doesn't seem to be sent/receive the content of the files.*

I can use either browser to navigate to the URL of the CSS file itself and view the document just fine.

It's probably best explained with screenshots...

### In Chrome

**Chrome Network Page**

Everything up top looks like it downloads just fine. But note at the bottom Chrome reports "Failed to load resource" for all the CSS files.
[image]

**Chrome CSS Headers**

Everything looks OK in the CSS headers...

[image]

**Chrome CSS Content**

Except the content is empty...
[image: Chrome CSS Content]

### In Firefox

**Firefox CSS Headers**

Everything looks good (note that the 'content-length' header is identical to Chrome)
[image: Firefox CSS Headers]

**Firefox CSS Content**

And there's the content!
[image: Firefox CSS Content]

What gives? What could possibly be causing the content to fail to load?!

---

**EDIT:** I'm still pulling my hair out over this one. This only happens in Chrome. I've restarted/updated/cleared my cache a million times--I'm at a complete loss.

It's simple enough to avoid--just use a different browser to view the page--but *why* is it happening?!?!

Comment: Try Safari to see if it's only Chrome or if it's Webkit-related.

Comment: It does work properly in Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to upgrade your chrome, or to move to stable channel, if you are using the distribution repository archives.

I once faced a similar issue and followed the same course.

Comment: I'm using vanilla Mac OS X Chrome. Chrome reports being fully updated to 9.0.597.102. I just restarted to be sure as well. **EDIT: Oh and restarting did _not_ fix the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ad blocker or tracker blocker chrome extension installed, such as [Ghostry](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij); it can block some legitimate files. I have run into this problem. To fix it I added an exception for the problem site.